# How can I customize the NSdictionary using Mantle?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary, github-mantle

I have the following json string:

```
{"suit_id": 2427;
"suits": "http://img.prettyyes.com/1137-4930-1446175512.jpeg;http://img.prettyyes.com/1137-7665-1446175512.jpeg;http://img.prettyyes.com/1137-4783-1446175512.jpeg"}
```

So when use mantle to parse the json string with following file

testModel.h

```
@interface testModel : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *suit_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *suits;
@end
```

testModel.m

```
@implementation testModel
+ (NSDictionary *) JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{
            "suit_id":   "suit_id",
            "suits":     "suits"
            };
}
@end
```

How ever I would like to convert suits from string to a NSArray with multiple urls so I did following:

testModel.h

```
@interface testModel : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *suit_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *suits;
@end
```

testModel.m

```
@implementation testModel
+ (NSDictionary *) JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{
            "suit_id":   "suit_id",
            "suits":     "suits"
            };
}

+ (NSValueTransformer *) suitsJSONTransform {
    return [MTLValueTransformer transformerUsingForwardBlock:^(NSString *str, BOOL *success, NSError **error){
        return [[str componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] mutableCopy];
    }];
}
@end
```

But it's not working. The result is nil. When I override the wrong function?

Answer (score 0):

The method returning the `NSValueTransformer` for `suits` should be called `suitsJSONTransformer`, not `suitsJSONTransform`.

The format for the method name is `<propertyName>JSONTransformer`.